# Borrowing bioinformatic methods in other fields

Tags: bioinformatics

Have the bioinformatic methods like sequence analysis, genome annotation, comparative genomics (and many others), been applied to solve problems outside the field of bioinformatics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course! The perfect example is Gusfield book. Many of string algorithms came from bioinformatics. For example, sequence analysis algorithms are used in text editors.

PS: Algorithms on Strings, Trees and Sequences: Computer Science and Computational Biology, Dan Gusfield